# python-escpos QS Printer not printing

Tags: python, printing

My QS-5801 printer doesn't print out. My PC is running on Windows 10, have Python 2.7 and python-escpos installed. I tried this but it's not working.

```
>>>from escpos.printer import Serial
>>>ser = Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
Serial printer enabled
>>>ser.text('hello world') #nothing happened
```

The printer itself is ESC/POS compatible. I'm connecting to it via USB (prolific USB-to-Serial Comm PORT (COM3)).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the expected behaviour for your snippet. The text remains in the printer's buffer until a line feed `\n` is sent to terminate the line of text.

Assuming that your printer is correctly listening on COM1, you probably just want to modify your snippet to include a newline-

```
from escpos.printer import Serial
ser = Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.text("Hello world\n")
```

The [python-escpos](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos) README contains an example of this usage.